# magento pass variable from controller to another model

Tags: magento, model, controller, smtp, zend-mail

I want to send custom mail through smtp.
For which I installed http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aschroder-com-smtp-pro-email-free-and-easy-magento-emailing-for-smtp-gmail-or-google-apps-email.html.
Which works properly for every mail provided by magento as default.
Now since the admin is having mail Id of google apps , my custom mail is not received by admin.
So for this reason I want to Integrate my controller with the sending mail function of ashrodder extension.
**My Controller code:**

```
$frm = 'mail@domainname.com';
$to = 'admin@domainname.com';
$subject = "UPDATE";
$mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
$mail->setBodyHtml($message)
->setFrom($frm, 'Admin')
->addTo($to, 'Site Admin')
->setSubject($subject);
try {
$mail->send();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Mail sent successfully.');              
}
catch(Exception $e) {
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send email.');
}
```

My question is simple : How should I pass **[to,from,body]** variable to any other model/controller ?
Please Help .
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Would `Mage::register('some_name', $var);` work?

Answer (score 0):

I think overriding the  extensions controller would be the best solution.Check this link [How to extend a controller](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller)